# adding parallel Impedance 1

Tags: impedance

A homework problem tells me to find the equivalent impedance, so I added the series and parallel impedances just like I would a resistor; however, I don't understand how does one go from \$100/(12-16j)\$ to \$3+4j \Omega\$. My book just jumps to that conclusion. Can anyone please explain?

Comment: multiply top and bottom by the complex conjugate of 12-16j and simplify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To divide by a complex number, use the conjugate of the denominator. like so:

$$
\begin{align}
{100\over (12 - 16j)} & = {100\over (12 - 16j)} {(12 + 16j)\over (12 + 16j)} \\
\\
& = {(1200 + 1600j)\over (144 + 256)} \\
\\
& = {(1200 + 1600j)\over 400} \\
\\
& = {(3 + 4j)\over 1} \\
\\
\end{align}
$$